Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while trying to work with SoapElemens in Java
I am currently working on a Java application that retrieves data through SOAP requests and processes it locally. The program runs perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy and execute it on my development server, I encounter a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.
Here’s the full error message I’m getting:
[10/3/24 18:38:21:596 AST] 000000bb SystemOut     O 18:38:21.590 [FlowchartScheduler-1:1736220-172796990143100001] CFS ERROR com.unicacorp.interact.flowchart.FlowchartScheduler - (v.12.1.1.0.35 ${app.version.extra}) Error occurred during execution of flowchart: Main Balance Flow (1736220 - 172796990143100001) in session TestWhatsApp
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/om/impl/dom/ElementImpl.setParent(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMContainer;)V (loaded from file:/app/IBM/WebSphere/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/AppSrv01Cell01/interactRT_new_war.ear/interactRT_new.war/WEB-INF/lib/axiom-dom-1.2.15.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@3b3ac50a[war:interactRT_new_war/interactRT_new.war]
Here is the snippet of the code:
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    System.out.println("SoapBody"+ soapBody.getClass().toString());
    SOAPElement changeBillLimitEligibility = soapBody.addChildElement("changeBillLimitEligibility", namespace);
    System.out.println("FirstChildElement"+ changeBillLimitEligibility.getClass().toString() + "Children" + changeBillLimitEligibility.getChildElements().toString());
    

    SOAPElement requestInfo = changeBillLimitEligibility.addChildElement("requestInfo", namespace1);

The error occurs specifically at the following line of code:
SOAPElement requestInfo = changeBillLimitEligibility.addChildElement("requestInfo", namespace1);

Additionally, the logs indicate the following:
Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@ab28d66e[PL][app:interactRT_new_war]
Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST).
at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPElementImpl.setParentElement(SOAPElementImpl.java:724) ~[axis2-saaj-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPElementImpl.addChildElement(SOAPElementImpl.java:200) ~[axis2-saaj-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
at com.ibm.mccm.GetWaParams.createCreditLimitSOAPRequest(GetWaParams.java:514) ~[?:?]
at com.ibm.mccm.GetWaParams.getValue(GetWaParams.java:119) ~[?:?]
Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@ab28d66e[PL][app:interactRT_new_war]
Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST) called from class org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPElementImpl
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue, as I have been struggling to resolve it for over two days now.
